# Why does update_attributes break my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## Original Question

I'm running Rails 3.0.1 on Ruby 1.9.2. Here are the relevant model, controller, and view.

## Code

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :directory

  attr_accessor :new_password, :new_password_confirmation

  validates_confirmation_of :new_password, :if => :password_changed?

  before_save :hash_password, :if => :password_changed?

  def self.authenticate(login, password)

    # Check to see if the user exists
    if user = find_by_login(login)

      # If this is an directory user, authenticate them against their directory
      if user.directory
        return directory_auth user, password

      # Otherwise, authenticate them against the local database
      elsif user.hash == Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(user.salt + password)
        return user
      end
    end
    return nil
  end

  def password_changed?
    !@new_password.blank?
  end

  private

  def hash_password
    self.salt = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.base64 8
    self.hash = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(self.salt + @new_password)
  end

  def self.directory_auth(user, password)

    directory = user.directory
    directory.bind['%s'] = user.login

    ldap = Net::LDAP.new
    if directory.use_simple_tls?
      ldap.encryption :simple_tls
    end
    ldap.host = directory.host
    ldap.port = directory.port
    ldap.auth directory.bind, password

    return user if ldap.bind
    return nil
  end
end
```

**users_controller.rb:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new params[:user]

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "#{@user.login} was created"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'The user could not be created' 
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]

    @user.attributes = params[:user] # this works
    # @user.update_attributes params[:user] # this does NOT work

    if @user.save # I realize this is redundant if update_attributes is working
      flash[:notice] = "#{@user.login} was updated" 
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'The user could not be updated' 
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @user.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.login} was deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end
end
```

**users.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :login %>:
  <%= f.text_field :login %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :new_password %>:
  <%= f.password_field :new_password %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :new_password_confirmation %>:
  <%= f.password_field :new_password_confirmation %>
  <br>
  <% if directories = Directory.all.empty? %>
    No directories defined. You can <%= link_to 'add a directory', new_directory_path %>.
  <% else %>
    <%= f.label :directory_id %>:
    <%= f.collection_select :directory_id, Directory.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => 'None' } %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= f.label :admin, 'Administrator?' %>:
  <%= f.check_box :admin %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20101107005603) do

  create_table "directories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "host"
    t.string   "bind"
    t.boolean  "use_simple_tls"
    t.integer  "port"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "hash"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.boolean  "admin"
    t.integer  "directory_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I have another model/controller/view for directories that is very similar, but doesn't have virtual accessors or other model ids, and `update_attributes` works fine in it. I did a quick test app with `rails g scaffold users name:string password:string` and all CRUD actions work fine.

This was driving me nuts! I found a workaround, but I really want to understand why `update_attributes` doesn't work here. When I run the update action, I get this:

## TypeError in UsersController#update

can't convert nil into Integer

Rails.root: /home/force/proj

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in `update'

## Full Stack Trace

```
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `uniq'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:318:in `commit_transaction_records'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:165:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:204:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:287:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:126:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:34:in `update'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:435:in `_run__805567340__process_action__482539529__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:409:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:133:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:173:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:103:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.13) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:492:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:287:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:46:in `call'
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/force/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/force/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/force/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

## Request Parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"OvMUeM9hqfPASC0NS+Th07GELu6B+dQCCTtm3gWdJE4=",
 "user"=>{"login"=>"local",
 "new_password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "new_password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "directory_id"=>"",
 "admin"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Update User",
 "id"=>"13"}
```

## Full Source Code

If you'd like to give it a try, you can download the full source at http://github.com/sidewaysmilk/deezy and edit `app/controllers/users_controller.rb` to use `@user.update_attributes params[:user]` in the `update` action.

Comment: What does your schema look like for your user model?

Comment: Can you add what your params look like when to submit the form? (from the server logs)

Comment: I amended my question with parameters, a stack trace, and a link to the full source code.

Comment: You have an before_save callback on user to update the password if that field is not blank. That's where I would start looking

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I'll try poking at that. I just find it confounding that I don't see anything like that in the stack trace.

Comment: As a test, put `:null => false` for all fields (as far as possible) in your migrations. That might help locate when the problem is occurring (eg. a field could have been saved as null, but was not intended to be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I feel really stupid. I'm surprised nobody caught this.

In my model, I name one of my attributes. `hash`, so to access it, I would say `@user.hash`.

**ActiveRecord::Base#hash is [already defined](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/hash)!**

So I screwed up. When ActiveRecord was attempting to execute the transaction, it was trying to set a value like

```
@user.hash = password_hash
```

`ActiveRecord::Base#hash=` expects an integer, and `password_hash` outputs a String if the password is changed, and nil otherwise.

***So never name a column hash!*** Check the documentation when you're picking column names to avoid collisions.

Comment: Saved my day! `hash` is now on my mental blacklist for any kind of variable or field :)

Answer (score 1):

Without a full stack trace it's hard to say, but the error message "can't convert nil into Integer" is your key thing to track down. Likewise we want see the logs for a request that's failing. I think the Parameters: line of the log might shed light on the issue.

Update Below:

Can you pass the same params successfully to @user.update_attributes in the rails console?

```
rails console

user = User.find(42) # whatever a good test user's id is
user_params = {"login"=>"local", "new_password"=>"supersecret", "new_password_confirmation"=>"supersecret", "directory_id"=>"",  "admin"=>"0"}
user.update_attributes!(user_params)
```

Does that behave any differently?

Comment: Of course. I'm sorry. I was pretty exhausted when I posted this question. I should have included the stack trace. I'll update it now.

Comment: I should have mentioned initially that using the stack trace I was able to track my problem to update_attributes, but I can't get any further than that. I don't know what the alleged `nil` is. I think it may have to do with my `attr_accessor`s, since if I set a password, it starts to say that it can't convert **String** (instead of nil) to Integer.

Comment: I cloned your source from github and changed the user controller's update action to use update_attributes and it works fine for me. This is with Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I'm going to assume that this is a bug with Rails 3.0.1 on Ruby 1.9.2. I really appreciate your cloning my source and giving it a shot. Thank you! I'm accepting your answer, and amending my question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what may be the problem is that the user id is a primary key and somehow that is being attempted to be updated. What is the error message you get if you use the 'bang`version of`update_attributes`:`update_attributes!` ?

Comment: I get the exact same behavior if I use `update_attributes!`. I'll see what I can find out about the @user.id being updated. That was a good catch. I don't know why my form is submitting @user.id as a parameter. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like submitting the id is normal behavior. I see the same behavior in a fresh Rails app using scaffolds.